# T-statistic of correlation coefficient

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation

Hi I am trying to calculate the t-statistic for a correlation coefficient between two vectors $x$ and $y$.

The individual vectors shows signs of autocorrelation. I have made use of the formula:

$\frac{r}{\sqrt{(1-r^2)(n-2)}}$

but I'm not sure this is the correct way of solving the problem.

The correlation between the two vectors has been calculated with the Excel formula for correlation.

Comment: The comment "show signs of autocorrelation" indicates you have a model in which $x$ and $y$ are viewed as time series (or something like them).  The question itself suggests a concern that the sampling distribution of their correlation coefficient will differ from that given by a theory in which $(x,y)$ are viewed as an i.i.d sample--and it is probably correct about that concern.  However, to address this question we need more information about the presumed underlying model. Could you edit it to explain what kind of data $(x,y)$ represent and *why* you are testing their correlation?

Comment: [Here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35c.htm) is something interesting I found after whuber's commentaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you should view your individual vectors as time series (because of the signs of autocorrelation you mentioned), you should be more interested in a cross-correlation function (ccf) of the two time series. This functions is essentially the product-moment correlation as a function of lag, or time-offset, between the series. This link [contains the relevant details](http://www.ltrr.arizona.edu/~dmeko/notes_10.pdf), including statistical significance of the ccf. The example considered is as follows:

```
Consider the two time series of annual tree-ring index plotted in Figure 1. The plots
suggest the series are positively correlated, but the year-to-year variations are too
noisy to visually judge whether one series tends to lead or lag the other. Both series,
however, appear to be positively autocorrelated, as positive departures from the mean
tend to follow positive departures, and negative departures tend to follow negative
departures.
```

The link above makes a reference to the 6th edition of Chatfield's  *The Analysis of Time Series* masterpiece (and the 5th edition will have that material in chapter 8 entitled Bivariate Processes) if you want to read more on this. In particular, if a test is required for a non-zero correlation between two time series, both series must first be converted to white noise (the book will tell you how) and then the usual theory applies.

Answer (score 1):

The degrees of freedom is n-2. this lets you test for whether rho (the correlation coefficient) is 0 or not. so calculate this value, find the p value using the degrees of freedom and decide if the null hypothesis of correlation coefficient being 0 is significant or not.

The autocorrelation of the variables do not have any effect on the correlation coefficient of the variables unless you want to check out if the lag of one variable has any affect on the other which the question does not indicate. So leave the autocorrelation part.

Comment: So you are saying that the formula used is the correct one? But the formula doesn't correct for the autocorrelation in x and y, and i assume this autocorrelation will have an effect on the correlation coefficient

Comment: please treat autocorrelations and correlation coefficients differently. what you have put up is for correlation coefficient between two different random variables only.

Comment: Your answer implicitly assumes the autocorrelation is irrelevant and as such it fails to address the key point of the question, and may even be misleading.